# Why there is an exceed color on the top of my hat?

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

help, i do not know what to do with this, why there is a yellow on the top of my hat when I am just putting a color infront? Thank you. Thank you. Pls pls need help. Somebody help me

Comment: Did you UV unwrap the object first? Share your Blend file and someone will be able have a look. https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: oh, thanks, I think that is what I skipped.. thanks.

Comment: I'll try again once more.